# What is the equivalent to Stata's portmanteau (Q) test for white noise in R?

Tags: r, time-series, stata

Stata includes a a command ([wntestq](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/tswntestq.pdf)) that it calls the "portmanteau Q test for white noise."  There seem to a variety of related tests in different packages in R. That said, most of these seem designed specifically for data in various time series formats and none that I could find that operate on a single variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Portmanteau" refers to a [family of statistical tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau_test). In time series analysis, portmanteau tests are used for testing for autocorrelation of residuals in a model. The most commonly used test is the [Ljung-Box test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ljung%E2%80%93Box_test). Although it's buried in a citation in the manual, it seems that is the test that the Stata command `wntestq` has implemented.

R implements the same test in a function called `Box.test()` which is in the *stats* package that comes included with R. As you can see in the [documentation for that function](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/box.test.html), `Box.test()` actually implements two tests: the [Ljung-Box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ljung%E2%80%93Box_test) text that Stata uses and the [Box-Pierce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Pierce_test) test. According to some sources, Box-Pierce was found to include a seemingly trivial simplification which can lead to nasty effects.[[1]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093%2Fbiomet%2F65.2.297)[[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau_test) For that reasons, and because the defaults are different in R and Stata, it is worth noting that the Box-Pierce version is default in R.

The test will consider a certain number of autocorrelation coefficients (i.e., up to lag *h*) and there is no obvious default to select (see [this question on the statistics StackExchange for a much more detailed discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6455/how-many-lags-to-use-in-the-ljung-box-test-of-a-time-series)). Another important difference that will lead to different results is that the default *h* or number of lags will be different in Stata and R. By default, R will set *h* to 1* while Stata will set *h* to [n/2]-2 or 40, whichever is smaller.

Although there are many reasons you might not want the default, the following R function will reproduce the default behavior of the Stata command:

```
q.test <- function (x) {
    Box.test(x, type="Ljung-Box", lag=min(length(x)/2-2, 40))
}
```

Comment: Stata's documentation of `wntestq` is accessible to all at http://www.stata.com/manuals13/ts.pdf pp.785-7. That includes citations and definitions.

Comment: This is the reference given in the original question. From a Stata point of view, nothing is "buried". The manuals (historically printed separately, but now online and accessible to all) are where citations and technical details are given.

Comment: By buried, I only meant that the method used was not prominent in the document or, as it is in R, in the *name* of the function. It wasn't meant as criticism of Stata. I spent half an hour searching for "portmanteau q test" in R before I realized it was called Box test. That's it.

Comment: I note that you are commenting rather than criticising. Equally, I suggest, the habit in statistics of naming tests after authors is not always especially helpful (nor, quite different point, is identifying the right authors to cite always straighforward). So, using a title like Stata's is intended to be helpful too. The references to authors are also given.